# selecting data from cassandar using cql

Tags: java, jdbc, cassandra, cql

i am using cassandra-jdbc to perform the operation on data in cassandra but when i run this simple program i get exception.

this is my code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.sql.*;
public class Operations 
{
        public static void main(String[] args){ 
        try
        {
            Class.forName("org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver");
            Connection con =     DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:cassandra://localhost:9160/temp");

            String qry = "select name FROM cql";

            Statement smt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = smt.executeQuery(qry);
            System.out.println(resultSet);
            while(resultSet.next())
            {
                System.out.println(resultSet);
            }


        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(" : "+e.getMessage());
        }
            }
}
```

i got   :cannot parse 'name' as hex bytes

Comment: You really need to include your CREATE TABLE statements in questions about CQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
import static org.apache.cassandra.utils.Hex.bytesToHex;
...

String name = bytesToHex("name".getBytes());
String qry = "select '" + name + "' FROM cql";
```